# Debian package drop datebase on purge

Tags: database, deb

i am on creating a deb package for ubuntu

in my postinst script i use

```
# Configure database
dbc_mysql_createdb_encoding="UTF8"

if ! dbc_go portal3 $@ ; then
    echo 'Automatic configuration using dbconfig-db_version 2.0common failed!'
fi
```

to create the database what works fine.

In the postrm file i have:

```
echo "Remove database"
if [ -f /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]; then
    . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
fi
if [ -f /usr/share/dbconfig-common/dpkg/postrm ]; then
    . /usr/share/dbconfig-common/dpkg/postrm
    if ! dbc_go portal3 $@ ; then
        echo 'Automatic configuration using dbconfig-common failed!'
    fi
fi
```

but this don’t drop the created user or database.
There is no response on console or anything else that helps me to debug the issue.

Has anyone an idea how to drop database and user created while installation?

Answer (score 0):

It also requires an prerm script like

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
. /usr/share/dbconfig-common/dpkg/prerm.mysql
if ! dbc_go portal3 $@ ; then
    echo 'Automatic configuration using dbconfig-common failed!'
fi

# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.

exit 0
```

Otherwise dbconfig-commond dont know what database needs to be dropt.

Comment: But this would drop the database on removal, not purge?

Comment: yes this is true. I have not found out how to drop database only on purge.  In my example the prerm drops the database and the postrm drops the dbcommon configs (like passwords). Because in prerm i can not differ remove and purge.